# "Always is always wrong"

Tags: paradox

Is this a paradox? I am too drunk to think it through (forgive my idiocy!).

If it is - can a paradoxical solution be qualified as "wrong"?

If so, is "always is always wrong" actually an explicitly not-wrong statement?

Comment: Hey again! This question could use a little more context and motivation. It might be constructive to read some of the [help pages about question structure](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). --Is there any chance you could consider expanding this a bit to include information on why this problem has become an important or interesting one for you in your study of philosophy?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, it is a paradoxical statement.

Paradoxical statements do not describe real situations or occurrences.  They cannot be evaluated to either true or false because the thing they describe, according to the laws of logic, are not possible.

Therefore "always is always wrong" is a nonsensical statement.  It is not true, false, not-true, or not-false.  It is paradoxical and describes nothing that is comprehensible.

If you wish to allow irrationality to exist, of course, then it can exist - we just can make no statement definitive statement about it at all, as it does not conform to the existence/universe that we have knowledge of.

Comment: I was just wondering whether, it could be argued that a paradox is outside the scope of the concept of 'right;, and whether therefore, the recursive conclusion to this statement - the paradox - can be argued to be 'not-right'.. not 'wrong' - that "feels" too strong (I know, weak - but I'm not educated in terms! :p ), rather a paradox doesn't seem "correct" to me, making the original statement justifiably accurate, rather than paradoxical! .. (I argue this as a curious case that can be put against a concept of the Absolute! :D )

Comment: I interpret the statement to indicate that there can be no absolute statement which is always true.  Such a statement is, of course, and absolute statement, and therefore, by its own logic, cannot always be true.  "Always wrong" here seems to clearly mean "not always", and thus we can determine true/false which are better logical terms to use than right and wrong, which can be very subjective.